# Ffmpeg not getting thumbnails at set rate

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, png, jpeg, intervals

This line of code works perfectly to make .pngs

```
ffmpeg -i path/video.mp4 -f image2 -vf fps=fps=1/60 path/%03d.png
```

But the problem is i would like the output to be .jpg i tried the same line with a different ext but i get errors in the command line any suggestions?

i.e. `ffmpeg -i path/video.mp4 -f image2 -vf fps=fps=1/60 path/%03d.jpg`

errors with the jpg command.

**{****NOT** a error seemed important

```
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 854x480 

  [SAR 1:1 DAR 427:240], 1352 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 50 tbc
```

**}**

> **ERRORS IN COMMAND LINE**
>
> [mjpeg @ 000000000482c9a0] bitrate tolerance too small for bitrate
>
> [mjpeg @ 000000000481d020] ff_frame_thread_encoder_init failed
>
> Stream mapping:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 -> mjpeg)
>
> Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters

such as bit_rate, rate, width or height

Comment: You should include the complete ffmpeg console output and not just a section.

Answer (score 1):

`ffmpeg -i ./video  -f image2 -vf  fps=1 ./%03d.jpg`

this worked quite nicely, make sure you do not give paths that have folders in the output path (if they are not already made) ffmpeg won't make the directories for you.